# Yii2 How to translate SUM SQL function to Query Builder?

Tags: sql, postgresql, yii2, query-builder

I have this simple SQL query:

```
SELECT product_name, SUM (product_amount) 
FROM orders
GROUP BY product_name;
```

It will show a list with product names and their amounts. Like this example:

[image: SQL query result]

I want to translate it to Yii2 Query Builder.  I don't know how to use the `SUM` function.  I tried this but it didn't work:

```
Orders::find()
    ->select(
        [
            Orders::tableName() . ".product_name",
            (new \yii\db\Query())->sum(Orders::tableName() . ".product_amount")
        ]
    )
    ->groupBy(
        [
            Orders::tableName() . '.product_name',
            Orders::tableName() . '.product_amount'
        ]
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`yii\db\Expression`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-expression#$expression-detail) while selecting as you are trying to call the SQL `SUM()` function and you need **not** to quote the function while selecting.

> Expression represents a DB expression that does
>   not need escaping or quoting. Expression objects are mainly created for passing raw SQL expressions to methods of `yii\db\Query`, `yii\db\ActiveQuery` and related classes.

Change your code to

```
Orders::find()
    ->select(['product_name', new \yii\db\Expression('SUM(product_amount)')])
    ->groupBy('product_name,product_amount')
    ->all();
```