# Assign uuid to a model in yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Is there any way to assign a database function-call to a model attribute in `Yii2`?

Something like:

```php
$myModel->myAttribute = 'mysql:UUID()';
$myModel->save();
```

Or how would i do this, if i want to fill the attribute with the `uuid` on save?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 How to translate SUM SQL function to Query Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53083764/yii2-how-to-translate-sum-sql-function-to-query-builder)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you could do is using the yii\db\Expression class:

```
$myModel->myAttribute = new yii\db\Expression('UUID()');
$myModel->save();
```

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-expression

And if you want to set the UUID on create insert the following function in your model class:

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
        if($insert === self::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT){
                $this->myAttribute = new yii\db\Expression('UUID()');
        }
        return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}
```

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#beforeSave()-detail

Comment: Perfect. yii\db\Expression is exactly what i was looking for. Thx bro.

Answer (score 1):

To generate the UUID during CREATE action add the following function to your MODEL if get any error to save

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if ($this->isNewRecord)
        $this->myAttribute = new yii\db\Expression('UUID()');
    return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}
```