# Yii 2.0 query builder - Select text as column (without grave/back tick/back quote)

Tags: sql, yii, yii2, query-builder, yii2-active-records

*Asking a question that I've spent the last 2 hours trawling the internet to find and couldn't get a solution to, but finally figured out a solution so I'll post the answer here for future users.*

If I'm using Yii's query builder but want to set a column to be a string of predefined text not a column itself. This happens when you use single quotes in the select statement, so it's both an issue for my date format as well as the 'All Sites' column.

```
$query = Department::find()
  ->alias('d')
  ->select("user_name, count(department) as departments, DATE_FORMAT(join_date, '%Y-%m') as join_date 'All Sites'")
  ->createCommand()
  ->getRawSql();
```

This returns:

```
Select user_name, count(department) as departments, DATE_FORMAT(join_date, `'%Y-%m')` AS `join_date` `'All Sites'` 
from `department_table` `d`
```

So how to I escape the 'All Sites' string and regex so that Yii doesn't inherently add back quotes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 How to translate SUM SQL function to Query Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53083764/yii2-how-to-translate-sum-sql-function-to-query-builder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this is as follows. I found that to solution for my date_format doesn't work for the string of text, as such I've given both variations on escaping the back quote issue in case either will help you.

*Note that in order to use **Expression** you'll have to include:*

```
use yii\db\Expression;
```

```
$query = Department::find()
            ->alias('d')
            ->select("user_name, count(department) as departments")
            ->addSelect(["DATE_FORMAT(join_date, '%Y-%m') as join_date"])
            ->addSelect(new Expression("'All sites'"))
            ->createCommand()
            ->getRawSql();
```

This outputs the following query:

```
Select  username, count(department) as department, DATE_FORMAT(join_date, '%Y-%m') as join_date, 'All Sites'
    FROM `department_table` `d`
```

Comment: you have extra quotes in the expression, also you need to wrap the `DATE_FORMAT` AND any other sql function inside the `new Expression()` too otherwise it wont work correctly

Comment: The reason for the extra quotes in the expression is so it'll put 'All Sites' into the query and keep the formatting. *I'm actively looking at it working here on my machine or I wouldn't have posted it*